# Why does cloning a remote repository with EGit plugin from within eclipse results in two local repositories?

Tags: eclipse, git, duplicates, clone, egit

When importing a remote project from within eclipse by the EGit-Plugin, it asks me first for a url and then for a path where the repository should be cloned to.

1. My eclipse workspace is located in `/home/me/Development/eclipse/workspace`.
2. I told EGit to clone the remote repository to `/home/me/Repositories/git/myproject`.

I noticed that eclipse cloned the repository to both 1 and 2.

I made a little change within eclipse and realized, that only the local repository in 2 is affected. The local repository in the workspace (1) is not affected.

Have I missconfigured my IDE somehow or is this intended?